# Java Socket Server and dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a working ServerSocket based java server and a client (based on AS3 XMLSocket).
This works out well on my IDE (Intellij).

However my java server uses a lot of dependencies like Bounty castle and JSON parsing libs as JARs. These are working in the IDE.

Once I export the java ServerSocket as a standalone JAR, the dependencies are not reachable any more. I always get the error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/BlockCipher
```

This is purely a class path issue.

Hence I tried to put all the dependency JAR's in a separate lib folder and the folder structure looks like

MyServer.jar
libs

and in the libs are all the dependencies. In the manifest file.. I have defined as

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: com.myserver.StartMe
Class-Path: libs/*.jar
```

but still the error persists. Did any one come across such an issue..with java ServerSocket ?. Would highly appreciate that.
thanks
Dom

Comment: This has nothing to do with Action Script.

Comment: Wildcards in the classpath work on the command line, but I don't think they work in the jar manifest. You should use the jar tool to generate it for you (or properly setup the jar export in your IDE). You might also think about building a 'fat' jar so you don't have external jar dependencies; everything is crammed into the one jar.